# What is the right term for adding a postfix to a file when it is downloaded a second time?

Tags: mac-os-x

e.g. If your FTP a file you can either **overwrite** a file or **write another version** of that file. Typical "-1" is added to the file.
What is the right term? Browsing learns that "**Increment**" is a possible term but I do not find it back in Apple's Human Interaction Guidelines.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Finally we named the option: "Add unique number to file name"

Comment: You are the ultimate judge of what to go with, but Gaurav's solution below is better UX to me because it doesn't require the user to understand what 'adding a unique number' is, but instead presents the user with two concrete answers to choose from: replace or rename (I wouldn't lay it out as densely as Windows, but their ux approach is pretty good I think)

Answer (score 2):

Technically I think **Append a file number** would be correct. I think you should try to make this **as least technical** as possible. Append, Increment may be a little uncomfortable to the conventional user.

My advice would be that you still follow your renaming strategy but inform the User that you are renaming the file. Eg: In Win7.

[image: Windows 7 Renaming a file]

Of course if you have a power user (which you typically might have for FTP) you might stick to your original notation as they would like to be informed as to *how* the file is going to be renamed.